# Is there a way to do this without each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many table cells which I want to show a tooltip once hovered. Each td element has a rel attribute with a request URI for ajax to fetch content into a tooltip. Right now I do it like this:

```
$('table td.tooltipped').each(function() {
    var uri = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).bt({
        ajaxPath: uri,
        ajaxError: "<strong>Error!</strong> Here's what we know: <em>%error</em>."
    });
});
```

It seems a little redundant to me but I can't figure out how to do it without the each loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use each? It doesn't smell for me.

Comment: I don't think that it has to be changed. at least for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation:](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html#ajax-content)

> **Ajax dynamic path:**
>
> **AjaxPath** is being read from the 'href' value of the link. This is accomplished by defining the ajaxPath as an array. **The first value of the array is the jQuery code to find the path value** (in this case "$(this).attr('href')")...

So it would seem that you can do this:

```
$('table td.tooltipped').bt({
    ajaxPath: ['$(this).attr("rel")'],
    ajaxError: "<strong>Error!</strong> Here's what we know: <em>%error</em>."
});
```

I'll let you test it.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine with `each`, since `.bt()` probably can't handle the referencing of each elements itself in a parameter list. You can leave the `uri` declaration if you want, and spare a tiny bit of memory:

```
$('table td.tooltipped').each(function() {
    $(this).bt({
        ajaxPath: $(this).attr("rel"),
        ajaxError: "<strong>Error!</strong> Here's what we know: <em>%error</em>."
    });
});
```

Comment: Most plugins handle iteration just fine. It's a question of support for pointing it to the `rel` attribute.

Comment: Actually you had the advantage of recognizing the plugin from the function name. Your solution from the documentation should work fine.

Comment: Actually I never heard of the plugin. Just googled "jQuery bt plugin" and it was the first result. Followed the links to the documentation, and there's the answer. ;o)